# Flutter: Rebuild a widget in using IndexedStack?

Tags: flutter

I know the purpose of IndexedStack is to display one widget at a time from cache to prevent widgets to be rebuilt.
But there are some situations where data in a widget has to be updated.
Now consider the following code example and let's say I want the page 1 to be rebuilt whenever I tap on the Increment tab (ie: whenever I switch from the Decrement tab to the Increment tab):

home.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Widget> pages = [Page1(), Page2()];
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Save Page State'),
      ),  

      body: IndexedStack(
        index: selectedIndex,
        children: pages,
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.plus_one_outlined),
            label: 'Increment',
          ),  
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.exposure_minus_1_outlined),
            label: 'Decrement',
          ),  
        ],  
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: (index){
            setState(() {
                selectedIndex = index;
            }); 
        },  
      ),  
    );  
  }
}
```

page1.dart

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();

}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text(
            '$count',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
          ),  
        ),  
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              count++;
            }); 
          },  
          child: Text('Increment'),
        )   
      ],  
    );  
  }
}
```

page2.dart

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State(); 
} 

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  int count = 0;               

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(             
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [              
        Center(
          child: Text(
            '$count',          
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
          ),                   
        ),                     
        ElevatedButton(        
          onPressed: () {      
            setState(() {      
              count--;
            });
          },
          child: Text('Decrement'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How can I do that ?
I tried to remove the Page1 widget from the list then add it again with `removeAt` and `insert` but it doesn't work.
Any Idea ?

Comment: "I know the purpose of IndexedStack is to display one widget at a time from cache to prevent widgets to be rebuilt" - it is not a real purpose (there is no cache here), just do: `children: [Page1(), Page2()]`

Comment: @pskink `children: [Page1(), Page2()]` doesn't work.

Comment: so you mean that `Page1` and `Page2` are not rebuilt? did you try to add some `print` inside their `build` method? if so what do you see on the logs?

Comment: @pskink Yes, `Page1` and `Page2` are not rebuilt. I put a `print()` inside their build method but curiously enough it's printed in the console whatever I do (taping on the page button or on the tabs). The behavior is the same with `children: pages`

Comment: i don't get it: you see `print()`s coming from `build()` method but you say they are not rebuilt?

Comment: @pskink Yes, the numbers on the pages are not reset to zero. Now if I use  `body: pages[selectedIndex]` instead of the `IndexedStack` widget,  the numbers on the pages are reset. I have no idea why `print()` is displayed anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the widget from the list then add it again with `removeAt` and `insert` ultimately does the trick, but a `UniqueKey` has to be used along to force the widget life cycle to start over.

```
// page1.dart
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
 Page1({ Key? key }) : super(key: key); // <= Add key

 @override
 _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();

}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
    Center(
      child: Text(
        '$count',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
      ),  
    ),  
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          count++;
        }); 
      },  
      child: Text('Increment'),
    )   
  ],  
);  
}
}


// home.dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Widget> pages = [Page1(), Page2()];
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Save Page State'),
      ),  

      body: body(selectedIndex),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.plus_one_outlined),
            label: 'Increment',
          ),  
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.exposure_minus_1_outlined),
            label: 'Decrement',
          ),  
        ],  
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: (index){
            setState(() {
                selectedIndex = index;
            }); 
        },  
      ),  
    );  
  }

  body(selectedIndex) {
      // Check for Page1.
      if (selectedIndex == 0) {
          pages.removeAt(0);
          // Pass a UniqueKey as key to force the widget lifecycle to start over.
          pages.insert(0, new Page1(key: UniqueKey()));
      }   

      return IndexedStack(
        index: selectedIndex,
        children: pages,
      );  
  }
}
```